# Check box to select and deselect all other check boxes in spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that pulls line items in with check boxes for each line item. I would like to put a check box at the top that will select and deselect all the other check boxes in the spreadsheet when it is selected/deselected. Following is the code I have so far which will select all the check boxes if my "Check Box 1" is selected but it won't deselect them if it is deselected. What do I need to add to make the boxes also deselect if "Check Box 1" is deselected. Thanks for any help.

```
Sub SelectAllCheckBox()
Dim CB As CheckBox
If ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value Then
    For Each CB In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        If CB.Name <> ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Name Then
            CB.Value = True
        End If
    Next CB
End If
End Sub
```

I am also running into another problem. I have a macro to clear the sheet so different macros can run. This macro has code in it that deletes all check boxes. How would I word the code to make it not delete "Check Box 1". This is the code I have.

```
Sheets("Quote Sheet").Select
Range("D3:D7").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Rows("11:1000").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Delete
Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
```

I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
Sheets("Quote Sheet").Select
Range("D3:D7").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Rows("11:1000").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
If CB.Name <> ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Name Then    
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Delete
Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub SelectAllCheckBox()
    Dim CB As CheckBox

    For Each CB In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        If CB.Name <> ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Name Then
            CB.Value = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value
        End If
    Next CB

End Sub
```

Second part:

```
Dim CB as CheckBox, n as long, x as long

n = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Count

For x = n to 1 Step -1        
    Set CB = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(x)
    If CB.Name <> "Check Box 1" Then CB.Delete

Next x
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, this worked perfectly. I tried doing something like that but didn't know how to word it correctly.

Comment: Tim, I posted another question above if you have a quick solution to that one it would be greatly appreciated. I feel like I am on the right track I just don't know exactly how to word it.