# Run Macro on All Checkboxes in Excel from a Single Checkbox

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have the following code (credit Tim Williams, here [Check box to select and deselect all other check boxes in spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301445/check-box-to-select-and-deselect-all-other-check-boxes-in-spreadsheet))

```
Dim CB As checkbox
For Each CB In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
If CB.Name <> "Expand All Checkbox" Then
CB.Value = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Expand All Checkbox").Value
End If
Next CB
```

It works perfectly using a checkbox for selecting / deselecting all other checkboxes, but each checkbox is assigned to another macro (the same macro, simply called "checkbox"). I would like to call the "checkbox" macro as each of the other checkboxes is selected / deselected - is that possible? If so, how?!

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim CB As checkbox
For Each CB In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
If CB.Name <> "Expand All Checkbox" Then
CB.Value = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Expand All Checkbox").Value
Call Checkbox
End If
Next CB
```

Try this, I believe this is what you are trying to do.

Comment: If only it were that simple! Thanks for the answer, but the problem with this method is that the macro "checkbox" contains code that is relative to the position of the checkbox that was clicked. So this method would execute the macro n times relative to the position of the "Expand All Checkbox", rather than executing the macro from each individual checkbox (CB) itself.

Comment: I have edited the code - basically you need to call **CB.Select** before calling **Call Checkbox**, this would cause that you can reference CB by it's coordinates