# Selecting specific check boxes using a master check box

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro to select all check boxes of a certain column.
For example I have 10 criteria check boxes per column with master check box for each column as "select all". 
I have the code down to select EVERY check box but cannot figure out how to tweak it slightly to only select or deselect cells A2:A10 for example, and not the boxes in column B, C, etc.

I'm using this simple script;

```
Sub SelectAll_Click()
Dim CB As Checkbox
For Each CB In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
If CB.Name <> ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Name Then
CB.Value = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value
End If
Next CB
End Sub
```

I tried unsuccessfully altering the <,>, = of the check box name to identify say anything less than the first checkbox of column B
As well as adding in an =range()

I am brand new to all of this and I'm sure with time and learning I'll look back and laugh at my road block here, but if anyone could lend me their expertise for the time being, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What are you using - form control or activex control?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check box to select and deselect all other check boxes in spreadsheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301445/check-box-to-select-and-deselect-all-other-check-boxes-in-spreadsheet)

Comment: form control **sorry

Comment: I have already browsed the suggested post. I am not having trouble selecting all the check boxes or deselecting all the check boxes, it's that I want a check box for each column, to only select the boxes below it. e.g. check box in A1 selects all of A:A but nothing in column B,C,D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have one macro work for all Master-Checkboxes use caller and compare topleftcell.column:

```
Sub CheckComboboxesInColumn()
Dim CallerString As String, CallerBox As CheckBox
Dim chk As CheckBox

    CallerString = Application.Caller
    Set CallerBox = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(CallerString)

    For Each chk In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        If chk.TopLeftCell.Column = CallerBox.TopLeftCell.Column Then chk.Value = CallerBox.Value
    Next chk
End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for originally thank you. 
Because I had swapped out my master check boxes with a button I tried to alter the string to identify the button but failed so have since converted my spreadsheet back to all checkboxes.
I'm assuming it's more complicated than  replacing the lead check box identifier as a button.

Answer (score 0):

If you reference the checkboxes as Shape objects within the sheet then you can access the property .TopLeftCell which will tell you what column the checkbox is located in. The following code will work for all form control check boxes in Column A. Simply change the column # (1 in this code) to the column you wish, and change the name of your master checkbox in each case.

```
Sub SelectAllColumnA_Click()
Dim shp As Shape
For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If shp.Type = msoFormControl Then 'Form control
        If shp.FormControlType = xlCheckBox Then
            If shp.Name = "Check Box 1" Then
                'Do not alter value of master check box "Check Box 1"
            ElseIf shp.TopLeftCell.Column = 1 Then
                shp.ControlFormat.Value = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next shp
End Sub
```

Edit: I simplified the code since you said you are using form controls.

Edit2: Here is a simple addition which will change the state of the master checkbox.

```
Sub SelectSubCheckBoxA()
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value = 2
End Sub
```

Simply assign this macro to every checkbox in Column A. For other columns, create a new version of this macro and change the name of the master checkbox. This way, when you select any check box individually it will visually "disable" the master checkbox.

Comment: Thanks so much, just tested and it works per column. The only thing is, the "master" check box remains checked at all times. I can select and deselect the entire column each time I click it, however the check remains in that box.  I was thinking it's not a big deal if I could just replace the select all check box with a button, but looking at the script, that wouldn't work.

Comment: That's strange, it seems to be working fine in my test file. Is there any other code in your module which could also alter the checkbox? Perhaps you're triggering another event which then edits the mastercheckbox.

This code should work with a button, just remove the check for the master check box (since this loops through check boxes, it won't see your master "button").

Comment: Thanks again swaffe,
It seems it was reselecting the master check box at the same time because it was in the same column as the "follower" boxes.
I did want the select all check box to be in the same column as the boxes it selects, is there no way to set the range rather than the entire column?

Comment: The idea is to check each checkbox within that column to confirm that it is not the master check box. Make sure you update the name of your master checkbox within the final If statement ("Check Box 1").

Comment: very happy with this thank you!
I'm now trying to figure out how to utilize this script to change the state of the "master" button if any of the associated check boxes are changed individually.
Rather than the select all button simply flip flopping the state of the cells to checked if unchecked and vice versa
I'm trying to pick parts of the original select all check boxes code I learned from this [tutorial](http://www.exceltrick.com/how_to/selecting-all-checkboxes-using-a-single-checkbox/)

Comment: In the original code I posted it would flipflop each check box, which I realized was incorrect. The edited version should assign each checkbox to the value of the master, so that there is no "flipflopping" and they all have the same value as the master. If you want to uncheck the master checkbox when any checkbox is changed, then you can do that is in the tutorial you linked. Simply create a macro to uncheck the master checkbox, and assign this macro to every subsequent checkbox.

Comment: I added a very simple sub to my answer which you can assign to individual checkboxes to do what you wish. If this works and you're happy, then please mark the question as answered. If not, I'm still happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want to check / uncheck your boxes based on the column in which they are located. Hence, I'd propose the following code:

```
Public Sub CheckComboBoxBasedOnColumn()

Dim chk As CheckBox

For Each chk In Sheet2.CheckBoxes
    Select Case Split(chk.TopLeftCell.Address, "$")(1)
    Case "A"
        'If the checkbox is in column A then check it.
        chk.Value = True
    Case "B"
        'If the checkbox is in column B then un-check it.
        chk.Value = False
    Case "C"
        '... what ever you want for column C
    Case Else
        '... or any other column
    End Select
Next chk

End Sub
```

Let me know if this solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't think this is really what I am intending. I don't want to deselect other columns while at the same time selecting another. I would be setting multiple master check boxes to select all of the check boxes in the same column. So master check box is A1, I want it to select all boxes in column A; another master check box in B1, selects all boxes in column B.